# Ensuring that a comma is not added if only one record is found, or that both are added

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014-express

Consider the follow piece of an SQL query that is designed to construct a complex return in the form of XML:

```
ISNULL(Logbook1 + ',', '') + ISNULL(Logbook2 + ',', '') + ISNULL(Logbook3 + ',', '') AS '@logBookNums',
```

In essence this will search the appropriate record. If it finds that no records exist for `LogBook1`, `LogBook2` or `LogBook3` it will return an empty string. If it finds one record in `LogBook1` it will return that and one trailing comma.

Unfortunately the WCF service to which this XML is being sent is appallingly documented (for which in truth read none whatsoever) and it is rejecting a single logbook number with a trailing comma.

My guess is that it should either be submitted as:

```
logBookNums="12345,,"
```

Or

```
logBookNums="12345"
```

How should I alter the above line of SQL to output one or the other, and (if the query finds two logbook numbers) to produce output like this:

```
logBookNums="12345,12346,"
```

Or

```
logBookNums="12345,12346"
```

This is the entire query into which I would need to insert a solution to handle this predicament for both @logBookNums and @landingDecNums.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.CreateErsSalesAddSubmissionXmlByDateRange

-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here

@uname VARCHAR(10) ,
        @pword VARCHAR(10) ,
        @sntype VARCHAR(1) ,
        @action VARCHAR(10) ,
        @salesContractRef VARCHAR(10),

        @auctionId NCHAR(10) ,
        @startDate  DATE,
        @endDate DATE


AS
BEGIN
  -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
  -- interfering with SELECT statements.
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  -- Insert statements for procedure here


 SELECT
    RTRIM(@uname) AS '@uname',
    RTRIM(@pword) AS '@pword',

    (SELECT

        @snType AS '@snType',
        RTRIM(@action) AS '@action',
        COALESCE(@salesContractRef, '') AS '@salesContractRef',
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DateOfPurchase, 112) AS '@saleDate',
        RTRIM(COALESCE(@auctionID, '')) AS '@auctionID',
        ISNULL(Logbook1 + ',', '') + ISNULL(Logbook2 + ',', '') + ISNULL(Logbook3 + ',', '') AS '@logBookNums',
        ISNULL(LandingDecNumber1 + ',', '') + ISNULL(LandingDecNumber2 + ',', '') + ISNULL(LandingDecNumber3 + ',', '') AS '@landingDecNums',
        COALESCE(VesselName, '') AS '@vesselName',
        RTRIM(VesselPLN) AS '@vesselPln',
        RTRIM(VesselOwner) AS '@vesselMasterOwner',
        COALESCE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), LandingDate1, 112), '') AS '@landingDate1',
        COALESCE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), LandingDate2, 112), '') AS '@landingDate2',
        COALESCE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), LandingDate3, 112), '') AS '@landingDate3',
        RTRIM(CountryOfLanding) AS '@countryOfLanding',
        RTRIM(PortOfLanding) AS '@landingPortCode',
      RTRIM(lh1.LandingId) AS '@internalRef',
        (SELECT

            COALESCE(RTRIM(SpeciesCode),'') AS '@speciesCode',
            RTRIM(FishingArea) AS '@faoAreaCode',
            COALESCE(RTRIM(IcesZone),'') AS '@ZoneCode',
            COALESCE(RTRIM(ld.DisposalCode),'') AS '@disposalCode',
            COALESCE(ld.FreshnessGrade,'') AS '@freshnessCode',
            COALESCE(ld.ProductSize,'') AS '@sizeCode',
            COALESCE(ld.PresentationCode,'') AS '@presentationCode',
            COALESCE(ld.PresentationState,'') AS '@stateCode',
            RTRIM(ld.NumberOfFish) AS '@numberOfFish',
            FORMAT(ld.Quantity, 'N2') AS '@weightKgs',
            FORMAT(Quantity * ld.UnitPrice, 'N2') AS '@value',
            COALESCE(ld.Currency,'') AS '@currencyCode',
            RTRIM(ld.WithdrawnDestinationCode) AS '@withdrawnDestinationCode',
            RTRIM(ld.BuyersRegistrationCode) AS '@buyerReg',
            RTRIM(ld.SalesContractRef) AS '@salesContractRef'

        FROM LandingDetails ld
        JOIN LandingHeaders lh
            ON ld.LandingId = lh.LandingId
        WHERE ld.LandingId = lh1.LandingId
        FOR XML PATH ('salesline'), TYPE)



    FROM LandingHeaders lh1

    WHERE lh1.AllocatedErsId IS NULL AND lh1.LandingDate1 BETWEEN @startDate     AND @endDate
    ORDER BY VesselName,lh1.LandingId

    FOR XML PATH ('salesnote'), TYPE)
FOR XML PATH ('ers')



END
GO
```

EDIT (what I have tried following answer below)

```
 SELECT
    RTRIM(@uname) AS '@uname'
   ,RTRIM(@pword) AS '@pword'
   ,(SELECT

        @snType AS '@snType'
       ,RTRIM(@action) AS '@action'
       ,COALESCE(@salesContractRef, '') AS '@salesContractRef'
       ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DateOfPurchase, 112) AS '@saleDate'
       ,RTRIM(COALESCE(@auctionID, '')) AS '@auctionID'
       ,(
        SELECT ',' + CAST(LogbookX AS VARCHAR(100))
         FROM
        (
            VALUES(Logbook1),(Logbook2),(Logbook3)
        ) AS x(LogbookX)
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ),1,1,'') 
AS NumList(Concatenated)
WHERE NumList.Concatenated IS NOT NULL AS '@logBookNums'
                ,ISNULL(LandingDecNumber1 + ',', '') + ISNULL(LandingDecNumber2 + ',', '') + ISNULL(LandingDecNumber3 + ',', '') AS '@landingDecNums'
       ,COALESCE(VesselName, '') AS '@vesselName'
       ,RTRIM(VesselPLN) AS '@vesselPln'
       ,RTRIM(VesselOwner) AS '@vesselMasterOwner'
       ,COALESCE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), LandingDate1, 112), '') AS '@landingDate1'
       ,COALESCE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), LandingDate2, 112), '') AS '@landingDate2'
       ,COALESCE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), LandingDate3, 112), '') AS '@landingDate3'
       ,RTRIM(CountryOfLanding) AS '@countryOfLanding'
       ,RTRIM(PortOfLanding) AS '@landingPortCode'
       ,RTRIM(lh1.LandingId) AS '@internalRef'
```

**Additional edit to help clarify comments from the answer below**

The full amended query now looks as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.CreateErsSalesAddSubmissionXmlByDateRange

-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here

@uname VARCHAR(10),
@pword VARCHAR(10),
@sntype VARCHAR(1),
@action VARCHAR(10),
@salesContractRef VARCHAR(10),

@auctionId NCHAR(10),
@startDate DATE,
@endDate DATE


AS
BEGIN
  -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
  -- interfering with SELECT statements.
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  -- Insert statements for procedure here


  SELECT
    RTRIM(@uname) AS '@uname'
   ,RTRIM(@pword) AS '@pword'
   ,(SELECT

        @snType AS '@snType'
       ,RTRIM(@action) AS '@action'
       ,COALESCE(@salesContractRef, '') AS '@salesContractRef'
       ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DateOfPurchase, 112) AS '@saleDate'
       ,RTRIM(COALESCE(@auctionID, '')) AS '@auctionID'
       ,STUFF
        ((SELECT
            ',' + CAST(LogbookX AS VARCHAR(100))
          FROM (
          VALUES (Logbook1), (Logbook2), (Logbook3)
          ) AS x (LogbookX)
          FOR XML PATH (''))
        , 1, 1, '')
        AS '@logBookNums'

       ,ISNULL(LandingDecNumber1 + ',', '') + ISNULL(LandingDecNumber2 + ',', '') + ISNULL(LandingDecNumber3 + ',', '') AS '@landingDecNums'
       ,COALESCE(VesselName, '') AS '@vesselName'
       ,RTRIM(VesselPLN) AS '@vesselPln'
       ,RTRIM(VesselOwner) AS '@vesselMasterOwner'
       ,COALESCE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), LandingDate1, 112), '') AS '@landingDate1'
       ,COALESCE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), LandingDate2, 112), '') AS '@landingDate2'
       ,COALESCE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), LandingDate3, 112), '') AS '@landingDate3'
       ,RTRIM(CountryOfLanding) AS '@countryOfLanding'
       ,RTRIM(PortOfLanding) AS '@landingPortCode'
       ,RTRIM(lh1.LandingId) AS '@internalRef'
       ,(SELECT

            COALESCE(RTRIM(SpeciesCode), '') AS '@speciesCode'
           ,RTRIM(FishingArea) AS '@faoAreaCode'
           ,COALESCE(RTRIM(IcesZone), '') AS '@ZoneCode'
           ,COALESCE(RTRIM(ld.DisposalCode), '') AS '@disposalCode'
           ,COALESCE(ld.FreshnessGrade, '') AS '@freshnessCode'
           ,COALESCE(ld.ProductSize, '') AS '@sizeCode'
           ,COALESCE(ld.PresentationCode, '') AS '@presentationCode'
           ,COALESCE(ld.PresentationState, '') AS '@stateCode'
           ,RTRIM(ld.NumberOfFish) AS '@numberOfFish'
           ,FORMAT(ld.Quantity, 'N2') AS '@weightKgs'
           ,FORMAT(Quantity * ld.UnitPrice, 'N2') AS '@value'
           ,COALESCE(ld.Currency, '') AS '@currencyCode'
           ,RTRIM(ld.WithdrawnDestinationCode) AS '@withdrawnDestinationCode'
           ,RTRIM(ld.BuyersRegistrationCode) AS '@buyerReg'
           ,RTRIM(ld.SalesContractRef) AS '@salesContractRef'

          FROM LandingDetails ld
          JOIN LandingHeaders lh
            ON ld.LandingId = lh.LandingId
          WHERE ld.LandingId = lh1.LandingId
          FOR XML PATH ('salesline'), TYPE)



      FROM LandingHeaders lh1

      WHERE lh1.AllocatedErsId IS NULL
      AND lh1.LandingDate1 BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate
      ORDER BY VesselName, lh1.LandingId

      FOR XML PATH ('salesnote'), TYPE)
  FOR XML PATH ('ers')



END
GO
```

when there are logBookNums then we are getting correctly formatted xml as you see below.

[image]

However when there aren't we should get logBookNums="" but as you see we get nothing.

[image]

Comment: @mhasan If Only!!  Sadly they must be inserted in the correct order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might try it like this

You'll need an "IN"-search, there's no search like `aNumber='123,345,678'`

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(Logbook1 INT,Logbook2 INT,Logbook3 INT);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 (12345,23456,56789)
,(234,NULL,NULL)
,(NULL,123,NULL)
,(NULL,NULL,NULL);

SELECT 'logbBookNums IN(' + NumList.Concatenated +')'
FROM @tbl
CROSS APPLY
(
SELECT STUFF
(
    (
        SELECT ',' + CAST(LogbookX AS VARCHAR(100))
         FROM
        (
            VALUES(Logbook1),(Logbook2),(Logbook3)
        ) AS x(LogbookX)
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ),1,1,'') 
)AS NumList(Concatenated)
WHERE NumList.Concatenated IS NOT NULL
```

The result

```
logbBookNums IN(12345,23456,56789)
logbBookNums IN(234)
logbBookNums IN(123)
```

Comment: If you  - as in your example - do not need the fulll search string but the number list only, you just've to remove the surrounding `logBookNums IN(...)`

Comment: I've been trying to apply your solution to my own query as show in full in my original question.  I've been assuming that I could work from the second parenthesis after Select Stuff, but not having a great deal of success.  Am I approaching this is the correct fashion?

Comment: @DomSinclair, you might take the 'STUFF(...) AS someName' and use it directly right where you need it.

Comment: I've added an edit showing what I've done .  when compiled this is showing me problems on the very last two lines:    FOR XML PATH ('salesnote'), TYPE)
  FOR XML PATH ('ers') putting red squiggles under the parenthesis after TYPE and under 'ers'.  Unfortunately I don't really understand what you were asking in your last comment.

Comment: @DomSinclair you must add the function's name STUFF before the opening para and - instead of the 'As numlist (concatenated)' you need your ' as xmlAttribut'

Comment: @Shunugo  Definitely making progress now.  This works well if there are numbers but is not returning lobBookNums="" if there aren't any logbook numbers.  Ironically that's the only bit my original query got right!

Comment: @DomSinclair please update your question with the last attempt.  Cannot help at the moment, but will do so a little later.

Comment: @DomSinclair, easiest was to surround the STUFF with "ISNULL(STUFF(...),'') AS '@logBookNums'"

Comment: Fantastic, you're a star.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can write it in Case When structure, it is not so long:

```
CASE WHEN Logbook1 is not null
        THEN 
            CASE WHEN Logbook2 is not null
                THEN 
                    CASE WHEN Logbook2 is not null
                    THEN Logbook1+','+Logbook2+','+Logbook3
                    ELSE Logbook1+','+Logbook2
                ELSE  
                    CASE WHEN Logbook3 is not null
                    THEN Logbook1+','+Logbook3
                    ELSE Logbook1
        ELSE CASE WHEN ...
```